# CodeIgniter doesn't parse php in empty path

Tags: php, codeigniter, dreamhost

When accessing my CodeIngniter Project in my development station everything works as expected, but as soon I upload it to the server(Dreamhost), it starts the download of index.php as plain text when I don't give any parameter to the path.

(home being the default controller)

Example: `"site.com/home"` correctly shows the site.
Example: `"site.com/asd"` Correctly gives 404 Not Found.
Example: `"site.com"` downloads index.php

My rewrite rule goes as follow(pretty standard for CI on dreamhost):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|css|js|humans\.txt|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Any Idea?

Comment: PD: Probably the problem isn't the RewriteRule :/

Answer (score 2):

This works for me - CI 2.1 (and I'm on Dreamhost):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L]
```

Comment: Works the same as mine, probably the problem isn't the RewriteRule :/

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, try removing the rewrite rules (or better yet, remove the .htaccess completely). This will allow you to see if it's your rewrite rules that are bugging you on your provider.

If you still are prompted to download the index.php file when entering the document root with your browser, it's probably related to the setup on your hosting.

Comment: Removing Rewrite and restoring index.php as index_page did the trick to make it functional, but the server stills prompt for the download. Gonna ask to support.